# How to show number of registered users in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm setting up a user dashboard, and want it to show how many registers users.

I tried multi things but it didn't work for me.

My code in the Dashboard:

```
<h5 class="card-title text-uppercase text-muted mb-0">Registerd Users</h5>
<span class="h2 font-weight-bold mb-0">$usersCount = DB::table('users')
```

My code in the User controller:

```
public function index()
users = DB::table('users')->get();
return view('user.index', ['users' => $users]);
```

Comment: You do not want to do `->get()`. It will fetch all data on all users every time. If you get thousands of users, that's an enormous amount of data. See the answer from @AbbasHMohammed for a better approach than the one you accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `count($users)` and it will work

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: users (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\msystem\resources\views\layouts\headers\cards.blade.php) (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\msystem\resources\views\layouts\headers\cards.blade.php)
Previous exceptions

Comment: Just change return to this 
`return view('user.index', compact('users'));`

Comment: Run this commands `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: i think yes , im using home controller , and to view im using cards.blade.php

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

```
DB::table("users")->count();
```

Or

```
App\User::count();
```

Alert : Don't use the php count() function .. there is problem in this function

Comment: This is a much better approach than the others. `->get()->count()` or `count($users)` will do `SELECT * FROM users`, which will bring your server to a halt if you've got many thousands of users. This approach avoids that issue (it'll do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users`, which returns just one row of data). +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
$users = DB::table('users')->count();
```

Also you can use in blade

```
{{count($users)}}
```

if your using this query

```
users = DB::table('users')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put the bellow code in blade file and it worked in php tags.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
$student = DB::table('student')->count();
echo $student;
```